# placeholder input field not showing value?

Tags: input, session-variables, placeholder

I have an **input box** with placeholder.and I am setting the value in this field via **Session** variable in php.

This is the code which I have written :

```
<input type="text" value=<?=$_SESSION['no_of_persons']?>  name="no_of_persons" id="no_of_persons" placeholder="No. of Person(s)" maxlength="3" />
```

and when I run this in firefox and watching the code in **Firebug** this following code is coming :

```
<input id="no_of_persons" type="text" maxlength="3" placeholder="No. of Person(s)" name="no_of_persons" value="7">
```

Problem is I am not able to see the value in textfield in the web page.

I go to firebug and edit html in firebug. What I do is when I press an **space** key at the end of input tag i.e after **value="7"** then the value **7** becomes visible on web page.

I am not getting why the browser automatically changing the sequence of attributes of input tag and also I already had closed input tag then why the browser not closing it.

I tried it in other browser also like safari,chrome but not working.

Please help me to get rid off this problem.

Thanks in advance!!! :)

Comment: Have you tried another browser? And what DOCTYPE are you using?

Comment: @FabianLauer I tried it on other browser also but not working and I am using <!DOCTYPE html> doctype

Comment: Just saw something:
Try wrapping `<?=$_SESSION['no_of_persons']?>` into double qoutes: `value="<?=$_SESSION['no_of_persons']?>"`.

Comment: @FabianLauer I tried it also but no success. :(

Comment: Can you show the html being generated? Not the firebug stuff, but the true html.

Comment: I did it. @FabianLauer I just changed the id and name then now it's working fine

Comment: Nice, glad it worked out for you.